# How to add Celltable Row Dynamically at the end of table in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Currently I am adding bunch of row to my CellTable using following method

```
    public void createTable(){
CellTable table = new CellTable(0,tableResource);
MyDataProvider dataprovider = new MyDataProvider(table);
setDataToList(myDataList);
}

public MyDataProvider extends ListDataProvider<MyModel>{
List<MyModel> dataList = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
public MyDataProvider(CellTable table){
    this.addDataDisplay(table);
    this.setList(dataList);
    }

    public void setDataToList(List<MyModel> models){
        for(MyModel model: models){
            dataList.add(model);
            refresh();
        }
    }

}
```

I am not seeing any data in the table. The whole table is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add elements to the list returned by ListDataProvider.  Then, call refresh() on your data provider to push the changes to the UI.

You also need to add the table to the data prvider:

```
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
```

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

I think an update to the celltable's dataProvider and then calling refresh should do the trick.

```
//add table to data provider    do only the 1st time
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);

//add new item to the list
dataProvider.getList().add(text);

//flush and refresh dataprovider for it to be updated
dataProvider.flush();
dataProvider.refresh();

//set celltable to new rowdata and row counts
cellTable.setRowData(0, dataProvider.getList());
cellTable.setRowCount(dataProvider.getList().size(), true);

//redraw the table with new data
celltable.redraw();
```

Comment: wouldn't this be adding to much call. if we have to redraw the table every time we are adding an item, then I would go with adding all item and redraw the table.

Comment: well if you are updating a number of rows you can use redrawRow(int absRowIndex) ... but for adding more data you need to call redraw, sadly there is no other alternative currently...

Comment: Thanks a lot but your solution seems to be slow to me.

Comment: absolutely. I will keep posted if I find anything better.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
MyDataProvider.getList().add(new MyModel());
```

Comment: Avoid the "two line" responses. Try to provide an explanation for the solution.